# Generators of an Ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals

Suppose $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, $I = \{f(\vec x) \in \mathbb{F}[x_1, ...,x_n]: f(\vec a_1)=...=f(\vec a_k) = 0\}$, where $\vec a_i \in \mathbb{F}^n$.  It's easy to see that $I$ is an ideal. How to find its generators?

If $n = 1$, then it's almost obviously generated by $(x - a_1)\cdot ... \cdot (x - a_k)$ (since $(x - a_1)\cdot ... \cdot (x - a_k) | f(x)$).

Is it possible to solve the problem in general case?

---

I'm solving a problem $\{(1, 0),(0, 1),(−1, 0),(0, −1),(1, 1)\} \subset \mathbb{C}^2$. It's rather difficult, I have a lot of computations now but still can't clearly solve it.

Comment: The ideal $I$ is the intersection of some maximal ideals, and these are pairwise comaximal, so the intersection equals their product.

Comment: In your example you have to multiply five maximal ideals: $(x-1,y)$, $(x,y-1)$, and so on. Some simplifications can occur: for instance, the product of the two maximal ideals above is generated by two polynomials: $x+y+1,xy$.